# Git, safest way to do the equivalent starting again and getting rid of local changes?

Tags: git

Ok, this question has been asked many many times, and there are dozens of different answers. Most involve reset of some sort, and each comes with caveats and special cases.

I checked out a branch, e.g. mybranch/develop. 
to test, I modified to some files (too many to fix individually with "get checkout"), and added some files (too many to manually delete)

Now I want to pull the latest version of mybranch/develop, which other devs have changed, but can't of course due to the local changes I want to discard.

I haven't committed, staged or anything.

My go-to method for starting again is to delete the repo, clone it, then checkout the branch again.

However, the repo is now 5GB, and in our office we only have 5Mbit so it takes days.  What I should have done is take a local copy of the repo before modifying files, so I can copy it back without risk.

I have tried to read the documentation on reset, but it requires one to have the significant mental faculties to understand the complex and detailed inner workings of git.

I am guessing I need to do "git reset --hard", but to avoid doing irreparable damage, I would like to check this wont break anything and is the "right" solution.

Really, what I want to do, is checkout the same branch again, and have it ignore (replace) the local changes which may include new files, new directories, modified files etc.

something like "git checkout -ignore_warnings" or "git checkout -force"

I see there is this command "git checkout -f BRANCH-NAME"

So could I do "git checkout -f mybranch/develop"?

If so, why is everyone recommending using reset?

== UPDATE ==

Ok, I tried "git checkout -f --" and it didnt work. It did get rid of the modified files error, but not the added files.

Comment: `git clean` for removing the added files...

Comment: So I need to do two commands: "git clean" and "git checkout -f --" right?

Comment: yes. `git clean -d -f` and `git reset --hard`

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout -f mybranch/develop` will not work because you try to checkout to the same branch you are currently at.
As you said, `git reset --hard` is the recommended way to easily get rid of all local changes.
If you afraid to run commands which cause deletion of things, you can play more safely by running:

```
git add -A
git stash
```

This will get rid of all uncommited changes by saving them aside in a stash.
If you regret what you did and wish to revert the process back, just run `git stash pop`.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-stash

BTW I do not recommend you to work with git without controlling those basics, take some time to dive a little deeper, it'll worth it.